# JavaScript: Why does my `new` need parens?

Tags: javascript

**I wanted to instantiate a constructor that was returned by a function, but noticed that `new` was a little quirky about it:**

```
  // This function returns a constructor function
function getConstructor(){ return function X(){this.x=true} }

getConstructor();       //=> function X(){this.x=true}
new getConstructor();  //=> function X(){this.x=true}

new (getConstructor());  //=> X {x: true}
```

Why are the parens needed?

Answer (score 3):

In the first case `new` invokes `getConstructor` function as a "constructor" for an object. That function returns another function (you've set it explicitly) - that's why `function X(){this.x=true}` is the output.

In the second case parens make the `new` keyword invoke the function, that was **returned** from `getConstructor` execution.

For better understanding:

```
function getConstructor(){ return function X(){this.x=true} }

var func = getConstructor();       //=> function X(){this.x=true}
var instance = new func(); //=> X {x: true}
```

Comment: `new new new function(){return function(){return function I(){ this.cannot='even' }}}` Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

Because `new` operator has **higher precedence** than `function call` operator.

If you want the constructor function returned by `getConstructor`, you have to wrap it to have the function call execute first.

Check the ***[Javascript Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)***.

Answer (score 0):

Without the parens, it looks like getConstructor is itself a constructor. Remember, `new Something()` attempts to create an object with the constructor `Something` (for example. `new String()`). But you want your constructor to be the function returned to getConstructor(), so you need parens to make the call to getConstructor() parse as a lone function call rather than as the operand of `new`.